# Stream publish (user/feed): Facebook is creating thumbnails on desktop, not mobile

Tags: facebook, api

When I publish a link on Facebook to a user via the PHP API using user/feed, I attach an image URL in [picture]. The image is 1200x650, and sometimes larger, but Facebook crops it to 116x116 on desktop like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fik0h.jpg

On mobile, it seems to be resizing to but to a bigger size (larger and with a better aspect ratio).

Can anybody explain why it's behaving this way on desktop and what I can do to force it to show large images, with a proper aspect ratio?

Thank you